# Hibernate FK reference issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data

I have an entity with reference to another one by FK, at the same time I have a field mapped on the same column to have access right to the identifier, let's say

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;
    
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Author author;

    @Column(name = "author_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    Long authorId;
}
```

so, for now on select via JPA repository (findById for instance) the field of "authorId" is always null, but in actual database it exists and object of "author" fills correctly. Tested in the transaction and outside - result is the same.

About app - it is spring boot 2.2.8 with spring data

Are there any ideas where I can be wrong?

*Update: found the reason - all the found entities are cached somehow, after detaching them from persistence context all data loads as expected. Seems it's clear, but still cant get where interactions with these entities appear, obviously not in my tx - it is pretty small and simple. Never thought that neighboring transactions can affect cache this way =((

Comment: Why you need extra column you can get it from `author.getId()`

Comment: Why do you need both Author and authorId in your mapping? With Author you can get the id?

Comment: @Eklavya It is required to avoid loading of the whole referenced entity, even more to make loading more obviously: let say if someone getting author - he can feel free to use all its fields, but if we don't want to load it we use only identifier =)) may be it is not quite correct, as I just read if we will get only identifier the entity would not loaded too or not? But still, it seem a little bit strange that it doesn't  work, I've used such approach year ago and it worked =))

Comment: Do it reverse. add insertable = false, updatable = false to relation. @JoinColumn(name = "author_id",insertable = false, updatable = false). Now authorId will load and when you need Author just call Book.getAuthor()

Comment: @Константин I  understand, maybe your lazy fetching is not working. It is only work when lazy fetch works

Comment: @anunaki may be I'm not quite familiar with this mechanism, but it seems that this is not good idea to make mapping (relation owner) to be  insertable = false, updatable = false =)) However I've checked it and, unfortunately it doesn't work too =(( I believe Eklavya is right, checked in debugger received objects and they are plain entity-objects, not proxy in my tx, so I'm going to research this way,  thx =))